# How to sort a field named 'Day of Week' as Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

This is my first time using MS Power BI. I am trying to figure out how to sort a days of the week that come from Excel as Monday, Friday, Wednesday, etc. I tried to add a Weekday function, and apparently that needs a Date, but all I have is Monday, Friday, Wednesday, etc. My source is an Excel Pivot Table. Do I need to go to the source of the Pivot, or is there a way to do Monday=1, Tuesday=2, Wednesday=3, and then sort descending?

Now, if I click 'Day of Week' and click the 3 dots (ellipsis), I can sort ascending/descending, but neither options sets it to this: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday. This is the sort order that I want to create.

Comment: In PQ, add a custom column where you add a number corresponding to the day of the week, and then sort on that.

Comment: I clicked Edit Query and Duplicate Column, then Replace Values (Monday=1, Tuesday=2, etc). This new column is now called 'DayNumber'. So far, so good. I have a Matrix visualization showing Monday, Tuesday, etc. How do I sort by 1, 2, etc., but NOT show the numbers and instead show Monday, Tuesday, etc.? I must be missing a step, but I'm not sure where it is, or what to try next.

Comment: Another way would be to add a custom column with the formula: `List.PositionOf({"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"},[Weekdays])`.  Then do the sorting in Power Query and delete the column with the numbers.

Comment: Nope. That wiped out my entire query. I had to close PBI without saving changes and revert to the previous version. I tried a Switch statement. That didn't work either. I found an example on YouTube that does exactly what I want. That example works fine; mine doesn't work at all. I keep getting 'Error: There is an unknown identifier'. I must be missing something, but I don't know what that something is.

Comment: You have not provided sufficient information for me to help you further. If you cannot figure it out, I suggest you **edit your question** after reading the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)